# Error installing Qt5 on Raspberry Pi 4 - Bullseye "Package qt5-default has no installation candidate"

Tags: raspberry-pi, qt5

I tried to install QT5 on my Raspberry Pi 4 OS version 12.3 64 bit with:

`sudo apt-get install qt5-default`

but I'm getting the following error

```
 "Package qt5-default has no installation candidate"
```

I've already performed

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

All of the documentation and forum posts I've read say that "qt5-default" is the apt package name.  Am I missing something that is different for 64 bit?  Is there no 64 bit package?

Answer (score 0):

```
Bullseye OS

$ sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev qtchooser
$ sudo apt-get install qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools
$ sudo apt-get install qtcreator
$ sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev
```

Comment: This worked great thank you.  Where did you dind it?

Comment: From my friend using qt5. I don't use qt5. We both using Raspberry Pi.